# Random audio ads

Tags: windows-7, windows, malware-removal, malware-detection

Audio ads appear at random and last for around 5-10 seconds before turning off. I've run spy-bot on my entire system and still ads appear. No recent program installations are appearing either.

Any suggestions (apart from muting my laptop which I will consider if I can't find a solution) ?

Comment: Does this happen only when a web browser is open?

Comment: If this is only happening when the web browser is open, it is the result of an ad somewhere on the page that is out of view. I have experienced this myself. Otherwise, if it is happening when no programs are open, your computer may have been hijacked. If the suggestions by DrMoishe Pippik below don't help, you will have to do some manual removal with the assistance of a site like [Bleeping Computer](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/f/103/am-i-infected-what-do-i-do/).

Comment: If you are using chrome then use Ad-blocker to avoid such kind of annoying ads

Answer (score 1):

This certainly is malware of some kind.

1. Remove any browser add-ons, particularly toolbars. In IE, choose *Tools*, *Manage add-ons*. In Firefox, it *Tools*, *Add-ons*.
2. Try a more complete scan with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/), [Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool](http://www.kaspersky.com/antivirus-removal-tool?form=1)
   or other free anti-malware tool. You may need to make a boot disk on a **clean** PC and boot from that disk to eradicate some malware.
3. Consider running a different AV suite than what you are currently using, and enable protection of browsers, e.g. in [Avast!](https://www.avast.com/en-us/index) select *Scan*, *Scan for browser objects*.

The biggest risk is that this malware is **intercepting everything you do on the web** in order to generate targeted ads.